# :before && :after pseudo elements not showing Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Firefox is not displaying :after and :before but they do show in Chrome.

Firefox & Chrome:
[image]

Viewing the source directly in Firefox shows the CSS is there:
[image]

This is happening on multiple elements on the page using :after.

I have tried using both before and after. I have also tried both :: and : variations.

If I use the same CSS in codepen it works:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXOZWL

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mobile_auth" />

.mobile_auth {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.mobile_auth:after {
    background-image: url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-gD_ItALdha8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAB4/eEbUyChzCJc/photo.jpg?sz=110');
    content: '';
    height: 33px;
    width: 33px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    left: 3px;
}

.mobile_auth::after {
    background-image: url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-gD_ItALdha8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAB4/eEbUyChzCJc/photo.jpg?sz=110');
    content: '';
    height: 33px;
    width: 33px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    left: 3px;
}

.mobile_auth:checked:after {
    background-position: right;
}
```

You can see the page live at: ***.com login with User: demo Pass: demo and click 'config'. Lots of buttons are missing in the latest Firefox.

It's strange because it doesn't show at all. It's not like the element is there and I can't see it. It isn't even showing that it exists in console.

Comment: To solve your problem, wrap your checkboxes in a label and put your pseudo class styles on that.

Comment: The only problem is that I cannot do the CSS checkbox trick and target the parent :after when the child is checked.

Comment: True. In that case, make the label follow the checkbox in the code and use `:checked + label:after`  selector.

Comment: No JS necessary here. Give your checkbox an `id="checkbox_id"` and attach the label to it using `<label for="checkbox_id">`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot use `::after` and `::before` on elements that **cannot have content**, such as `<input />` or `<img />`.

`::after` and `::before` work like this:

```
<element>
  ::before
  ***content***
  ::after
</element>
<next-element>***content***</next-element>
```

They get inserted before and after the *content* of a DOM node. Since `<input />` cannot have content, there's nowhere to put it.

Now let's check with a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<next-element>***content***</next-element>
```

Here, there cannot be ***content*** to surround with pseudo elements.

Comment: Thank you Connexo. The only thing that I'm still unsure about is the fact that it works on Firefox in the codepen with the same code?

Comment: A side note. Chrome supports after/before tags on the checkbox. Firefox doesn't.

Answer (score 36):

The expected behavior **can be enabled for Firefox browsers** by using the following on the `input[type=checkbox]`:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  -moz-appearance:initial // Hack for Firefox Browsers
}
```

This option allows you to use `:before` pseudo-elements on the input-element, just like it works out of the box for Safari and Chrome and Opera Browsers:

```
input[type=checkbox]::before { 
    ...
}
```

The `moz-appearance` is currently experimental technology. More information along with an overview of Browser compatibility can be obtained here: [MDN web docs - appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance).

Comment: Not sure if I would want to rely on this working.

Comment: The answer still works in 2022