# Adding content to input from :before css on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

For an input field, upon on focus, the input field should show "+91" as a static part. I am successfully able to replace the placeholder onFocus & onBlur activities. I am unable to add a listener to read content from :before

```
<div class="goal-mobile">
  <input id="mobileField" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your mobile number'" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" type="tel" class="input-mobile"/>
</div>

.goal-mobile{
    position: relative;
    &:before{
        content: "+91";
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
        color: rgba(3,3,3,.6);
    }
}
```

The above class loads "+91" by default,it needs to be loaded on focus to the input field
I tried using :focus::before{} but it didn't work
What can I use to achieve onFocus default static display of "+91" in input box ?

PS: Won't be easy to implement jQuery as I am using Vue JS framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:before && :after pseudo elements not showing Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378360/before-after-pseudo-elements-not-showing-firefox)

Comment: `::before` and `::after` are not part of the DOM, so you cannot access them with Javascript.

Comment: `before` and `after` are pseudo-elements which are wrapped in a element, but `input` can't wrap any element

Comment: Yes, thanks :) But isn't there a way to trigger the :before{} css on input focus & blur activities ?

Comment: No, because there is no parent selector in CSS. You can only select forward and downwards. Given you current HTML structure you will have to resort to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Like @connexo commented on your question, you won't be able to access content of ::before & ::after directly from javascript.

However, you could ask css to load content from the element's attribute & manipulate that attribute in javascript.

Add a new attribute in your div. I'll call this `data-num` for this example:

```
<div class="goal-mobile" data-num="">
  <input id="mobileField" type="tel" class="input-mobile"/>
</div>
```

Then in css, use `attr()` function to fill content:

```
.goal-mobile{
  position: relative;
}

.goal-mobile:before {
  content: attr(data-num);
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: rgba(3,3,3,.6);
}
```

Now you can set whatever string you'd like for that content in js:

```
const $mobile = document.querySelector('.goal-mobile');
const $mobileInput = document.querySelector('.goal-mobile input');

const phoneNum = '+91';

$mobileInput.onfocus = () => {
  $mobile.setAttribute('data-num', phoneNum);
}

$mobileInput.onblur = () => {
  $mobile.setAttribute('data-num', '');
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/rumahogunu/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

You won't be able to use `attr()` for anything other than `content`, but its support is pretty good: [caniuse: attr()](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

Please note that even though it works, this might not be the best way to achive what you want - you could easily do this with a real element instead.

Comment: @DazzlerJay Glad it helps! If it answers your question, don't forget to mark answer as correct so I can collect that sweet, sweet internet point 