# How to show yes no instead of check box in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a web page that got several check boxes on it.
When printing want to hide the check box and show "yes" or "no" depending on check box checked or not.
Is there a simple way to do it without going through java-script?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: no :p
google for ways to customize checkboxes - its hell! you can use CSS selectors and before/after to show some text, but to hide the checkbox you either put something over it or move it out of the viewport

Comment: @Lux wouldn't a CSS print media do the trick?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik it's just simple check boxes <td>
 <input type="checkbox" />
</td>

Comment: @Robert yes I'm using CSS print media and bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All thanks for the help,
I was able to do it using following code.
Please let me know what you think and let me know if there are better ways to do this.

```css
.yes-no-check-text:before {
  content: 'No';
}

.yes-no-check-input:checked ~ .yes-no-check-text:before {
  content: 'Yes';
}

.visible-print {
  display: none !important;
}
@media print {
  .visible-print {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .hidden-print {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
  <!--  Code that hides check box controller when printing and shows yes no depending
        on check box checked or not -->
<form>
 <input type="checkbox" class="yes-no-check-input hidden-print" />
 <span class="yes-no-check-text visible-print"></span>
</form>
</br>
  <!--  test Code to show yes no wording selecting properly with check box selection -->
<form>
 <input  type="checkbox" class="yes-no-check-input" />
 <span class="yes-no-check-text"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Actually this is good, but not the exact thing which you have asked in your question, check my answer once.

Comment: `input` elements cannot have `content`, and thus, no `::after` or  `::before` pseudo elements. Check your code in Firefox which implements this correctly.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378360/before-after-pseudo-elements-not-showing-firefox/35378410#35378410 for reference.

Comment: @connexo I tried this with all browsers and it worked fine..Thanks, appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

You could try some CSS rules

```css
input[type=checkbox]::after {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  content: "no";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked::after { 
  content: "yes";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: `input` elements cannot have `content`, and thus, no `::after` or  `::before` pseudo elements. Check your code in Firefox which implements this correctly.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378360/before-after-pseudo-elements-not-showing-firefox/35378410#35378410 for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type=checkbox]+label {
     display: none;
    }
    @media print {
        input[type=checkbox] {
            display: none;
        }
  input[type=checkbox]+label {
      display: block;
  }
        input[type=checkbox]+label span.yes {
            display: none;
        }

        input[type=checkbox]:checked+label span.yes {
            display: block;
        }

        input[type=checkbox]:checked+label span.No {
            display: none;
        }

        input[type=checkbox]::after {
            position: relative;
            left: 20px;
            content: "";
            display: none;
        }

        input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
            content: "";
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="yeNo" checked>
<label for="yeNo">
    <span class="yes">Yes</span>
    <span class="No">No</span>
</label>
```

This is what you want, copy this code in your html when you will do ctrl + P, see the result. Or you can just run the snippet here and press CTRL + P to see the result.

Comment: This is really good but in this way I have to set <label for="yeNo">
    <span class="yes">Yes</span>
    <span class="No">No</span>
</label> for all check boxes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

check this one

In your HTML

```
<div>
    <!-- Toggle Button Style 20 -->
       <label class="toggler-wrapper style-20">
       <input type="checkbox" >
       <div class="toggler-slider">
            <div class="toggler-knob"></div>
      </div>
      </label>
</div>
```

CSS styles

```
.toggler-wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.toggler-wrapper input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.toggler-wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.toggler-slider {
    background-color: #44cc66;
}

.toggler-wrapper .toggler-slider {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.toggler-wrapper .toggler-knob {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.toggler-wrapper.style-20 {
    width: 81px;
    text-align: center;
}

.toggler-wrapper.style-20 input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.toggler-slider .toggler-knob {
    background-image: url(../img/check-fill.svg);
}

.toggler-wrapper.style-20 input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.toggler-slider .toggler-knob:before {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.toggler-wrapper.style-20 input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.toggler-slider .toggler-knob:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.toggler-wrapper.style-20 .toggler-slider {
    background-color: #eb4f37;
}

.toggler-wrapper.style-20 .toggler-knob {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/close-fill.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -2px;
}

.toggler-wrapper.style-20 .toggler-knob:before {
    content: 'No';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -20px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 75%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
}

.toggler-wrapper.style-20 .toggler-knob:after {
    content: 'Yes';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -23px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 75%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```